# What is the best update mechanism for a software cataloguing application?

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android application very much like the the Android Market (now Google Play) in which I offer various softwares to user for installation. The difference is here that I want the user to be able to browse the applications even when there is no internet connectivity. That means I have to store the data on a local database (here I want to use sqlite) and this data needs to be updated periodically.
Now my question is this. How should I implement this update mechanism to have the best performance and availability?
I think I have a few options which is as following:

1. To update the whole database every time. This way I have to download every single record every time to have the updated content.
2. To update the data based on the date they were added. Although this seems a good way, but there is a possibility that the previously added content may be edited and they are omitted in this approach. Also there is this possibility that some of the items are deleted.

These were what I thought I can do but I don't know which is best way to go on?! Also I am open to any other suggestion that might work here.

Comment: How about storing edition dates? Then you know what records need to be updated.

Comment: You can do update if you found record id already in sqlite otherwise you can insert data.by it you can have updated data as well as new data.

Comment: Yeah waht @dreamcoder said, just give each record a unique identifier and keep a list. That way you know what each database has and what it needs updating with

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. @assylias Storing modification dates is a good way but what if there are deleted items. How should the app know some of the items are deleted?

Comment: @dreamcoder, Blundell That seems just the right thing to do. I think if there isn't any better way found in time I will do just what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my concern, If you put some listener for your server side database which are notified when any data record is modified, added or deleted. And using Web-Service or [Google Android C2DM Service](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/) it will notify your application to update for particular database record from your server.

(I may be wrong or any other method also available for easy implementing)